# How to georeference a web mercator tile correctly using gdal?

Tags: web-mapping, gdal, epsg, tiles

As an example I will take the following tile http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/3/4/2.png and save it as "4_2.png".

The WGS84 coordinates of this tile can be calculated or read [there](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) by clicking the corresponding tile:

```
0 66.51326044311185 45 40.97989806962013 (West North East South)
```

How to georeference the tile correctly (using gdal to generate a geotiff or another georeferenced format) so that:

- The bitmap don't need to be stretched (= the pixels in the geotiff are exactly the same as in the original bitmap)
- The resulting image will be opened at the right place in a GIS viewer/editor (like for example in [TatukGIS Free Viewer](https://www.tatukgis.com/Products/Editor-Viewer/Editions/Viewer-%28free%29.aspx))?

(Edited at Sept 19 2011 to make my question clearer and include my conclusions)

---

My conclusion:

I first though that the third idea (see below) was the right one. I opened the geotiff in a GIS Viewer and compared the displayed coordinates with what I expected. The geotiff out of the second idea seems to be shifted 2 pixels towards north. That is why I considered idea 3 (or 4) as the right one.
But if you try with a tile at a much higher zoom level, the geotiff out of idea 3 is definitively shifted towards south. It was silly to compare coordinates on a tile of zoom level 3. The country boundaries at such zoom level are mus simplified so that the comparison doesn't give good results.

**Dan S. was right, the tile image is already in EPSG:3857. The second idea is then the right one (and gives good result at high zoom levels too)**

---

**First idea: EPSG:4326**
The EPSG code for WGS84 coordinates is [EPSG:4326](https://web.archive.org/web/20220730123636/https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/). So I simply use the WGS84 coordinates to georefence the tile as geotif using [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -co tfw=yes -a_ullr 0 66.51326044311185 45 40.97989806962013 -a_srs EPSG:4326 4_2.png t4326.tif
```

The resulting map is displayed at the right place but I fear that the projection is not correct and that there might be a shift in the middle of the tile. After trying a long time to check that by reprojecting the map with gdalwarp, I downloaded a demo version of [Global Mapper](https://www.globalmapper.com/) and this seems to be the case (sames borders as by idea 3 but a shift inside the tile). The image should be streched to be able to use EPSG:4326 coordinates .

---

**Second idea: EPSG:3857**
This tile use a "web mercator" projection (alias google map projection), which now has an EPSG code: [EPSG:3857](https://web.archive.org/web/20220327071116/https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/) (alias EPSG:900913). I simply convert the coordinates using [gdaltransform](https://gdal.org/gdaltransform.html):

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857
0 66.51326044311185
0 10018754.1713946 0
45 40.97989806962013
5009377.08569731 5009377.08569731 0
```

My coordinates in meters are:

```
0 10018754.1713946 5009377.08569731 5009377.08569731 (West North East South)
```

Now I can use [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to generate a geotiff:

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -co tfw=yes -a_ullr 0 10018754.1713946 5009377.08569731 5009377.08569731 -a_srs EPSG:3857 4_2.png t3857.tif
```

<strike>My impression is that this is not correct because the borders of the maps are shifted toward north.</strike> It seems to be the right idea.

---

**Third idea: EPSG:3857 through EPSG:4055**
I read that "web mercator" uses WGS84 coordinates but consider them as if they where spherical coordinates. Due to the difference between a geodetic and a geocentric latitude (See [Wikipedia about the latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Common_.22latitude.22)), the latitude values will not be the same on an ellipsoid or on a sphere. I found that [EPSG:4055](https://web.archive.org/web/20201027011752/https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4055/) is the code for spherical coordinates on a sphere based on WGS84.

Converting the coordinates to EPSG:4055:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4055
0 66.51326044311185
0 66.3722684317026 -17964.0621483233
45 40.97989806962013
45 40.7894557844857 -9152.84527519904
```

The corresponding spherical coordinates are then:

```
0 66.3722684317026 45 40.7894557844857 (West North East South)
```

Then I do as if those coordinates where still on the ellipsoid (EPSG:4326) and convert them to web mercator:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857
0 66.3722684317026
0 9979483.26733298 0
45 40.7894557844857
5009377.08569731 4981335.86590183 0
```

The resulting coordinates differ from the one by idea2:

```
0 9979483.26733298 5009377.08569731 4981335.86590183 (West North East South)
```

Now I just have to write the coordinates into the map:

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -co tfw=yes -a_ullr 0 9979483.26733298 5009377.08569731 4981335.86590183 -a_srs EPSG:3857 4_2.png t3857_through_4055.tif
```

<strike>This third idea seems to give the best results.</strike> But I am not sure if it is correct. If idea 3 is correct, is there an EPSG code to do this operation in one step?

---

**Fourth idea: EPSG:3857 through towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0**

gdal (and apparently epsg too) defines EPSG:3857 like that:

```
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
```

whereas spatialreference.org like that:

```
+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

If I use the definition from spatialreference.org I got the <strike>correct</strike> coordinates in one step (Well I still don't if they are the "correct" coordinates but at least they are the sames as by idea 3):

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
0 66.51326044311185
0 9979483.26733298 -17964.0621483233
45 40.97989806962013
5009377.08569731 4981335.86590183 -9152.84527519904
```

Why is there such a difference in the definitions of EPSG:3857?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tile image is already in EPSG:3857. Why not just create a world file to reference it?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

For the tile that covers N. America at zoom 1, you'd be looking at the following worldfile contents:

```
78271.517
0
0
-78271.517
-19998372.6
19998372.6
```

Where those numbers came from:

- Line 1: width of an image pixel in world coordinates = 20037508.342789244 meters / 256 pixels.
- Line 2 and 3: rotation, so n/a.
- Line 4: height of an image pixel in world coordinates. Same as line 1 but negative, because in image files increasing y corresponds to 'down' while in the coordinate system, increasing y corresponds to 'up'.
- Line 5: X coordinate in world coordinates of the center of the top-left pixel. This is -20037508.342789244, as reported by the tiles a la carte link, plus 1/2 of a pixel to bring it to the center.
- Line 6: Ditto, only Y coordinate of the top left.

GDAL ought to pick up your worldfile (.pgw for the png); you'll still have to tell it EPSG:3857 on the command line.

(Note: didn't have time to test this, so it's all off the cuff... but hopefully correct on the first try anyway! ;)

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late answer. But actually I think this would lead to the same thing as my second idea, where gdaltransform is really only used to georeference the image.

Comment: You were right about the tile image already beeing in EPSG:3857. The solution was actually to simply use EPSG:3857. It's the way I used to check the results which was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Functions necessary for generation of global tiles used on the web.
It contains classes implementing coordinate conversions for:

- GlobalMercator (based on **EPSG:900913 = EPSG:3785**)
     for Google Maps, Yahoo Maps, Microsoft Bing Maps compatible tiles
- GlobalGeodetic (based on EPSG:4326)
     for OpenLayers Base Map and Google Earth compatible tiles

http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/sandbox/klokan/gdal2tiles.py

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't answer my question. I don't want to generate tiles. I want to know what is/would be the correct georeferencing of tiles.

Comment: I did "If it is correct, is there an EPSG code to do this operation in one step?" Answer EPSG:900913

Comment: You didn't: EPSG:900913 works like EPSG:3857 (or like EPSG:3785) and does no permit to do the operation in one step, you still have to go over EPSG:4055. Moreover I had already mentioned EPSG:900913 as an alias for EPSG:3857 in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

About my secondary question in the fourth ideas: Why is there such a difference in the definitions of EPSG:3857 between the definition in gdal and on [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/):

The main difference is that gdal uses "+nadgrids=@null" and spatialreference "+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0". According to [the documentation or the PROJ.4 format](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms#Parameterlist) both parameter are used for datum transforms. I found an [interesting comment from Mikael Rittri on the Proj4 listserver](http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2011-May/005700.html):

```
"The +to definition you suggest is not correct for WGS84 Web Mercator, though.
This is because the datum shift you use, 

   +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0

is not the same as unmodified lat/long, or "without any datum shift" as you say.
It means "no datum shift" only if the +from and +to definitions use the same ellipsoid,
and in your case the +from definition uses the WGS84 ellipsoid, while the +to definition
uses a sphere instead.  

So, you have to use a trick: use 

   +nadgrids=@null 

instead."
```

The use of "+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0" doesn't seems to be right or at least only under specific conditions.